# Electrical panel service entry

Tags: electrical

Apologies in advance as I do not know the terminology.  I will hire an electrician to do the actual work
I have a 200 AMP main disconnect that is approx 125 feet from my house. I will install a 200 AMP breaker on the inside of a closet.  What size wire, preferably aluminum, do I need to run to the breaker box, underground thru conduit.  and does this mean I will buy 3 seperate wires or does the wires come bundled?   950 sq ft house.  standard appliances.  Mini split heating/cooling.  nothing fancy
Thanks in advance

Comment: "inside of a closet"? You can't put a breaker panel inside a closet - it needs a 30" x 36" open and accessible space in front of it. Depending on how the disconnect is done ("only just a disconnect" vs. "actually a tiny main panel") it may be 3 wires, 4 wires or 3 wires + metal conduit (which functions as the 4th, ground, wire). As far as individual wires vs. cable - that depends on whether you use conduit (wires *much* easier than cable, cable not really practical at that size) or cable (generally easier overall installation), but that depends on local code and/or electrician preference.

Comment: I appreciate the information. Closet was probably not the correct description. It’s an interior room 5 ft x 6 ft just for electrical and a tankless water heater

Comment: **DON'T GET ELECTRIC TANKLESS WATER HEATER.**

Comment: What’s the issue with an electric tankless?

Comment: Draws way too much power. Often multiples of EV charging.

Comment: Hard to find parts for some of the older ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for 200A the NEC requires 250 KCM aluminum, but if it feeds the full load associated with a residential service there is an exception that allows 4/0.

A NEC prescribed "Load Calc" may not require a full 200A feeder for that size of house, and results of the calculation will likely allow the neutral and ground to be smaller than the hots.

Typically for underground the cable is sold in a [set that is unjacketed](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-500-ft-4-0-4-0-2-0-4-Black-Stranded-AL-MHF-USE-2-Cable-30161401/202316548), but can be purchased as individual conductors. Except where the wires rise above ground conduit is not required, but if used does allow additional options.

This is a DIY forum, it can be a bit perilous using information here to second guess the electrician that can see all the conditions that will be present when he calls for an inspection.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I just wanted the info so I can roughly calculate the cost of the wire before I move to the next stage of the construction process. Thanks again for the info!

Answer (score 2):

If you have any plan to fork power from the pole to outbuildings, you will need to make the box out on the pole the **service disconnect**, and run 4-wire w/ground to the house.   If nothing will ever tap at the pole, it can be labeled "Emergency Disconnect - Not A Service Disconnect" and run 3-wire. Probably.

Since the entire electrical service is 200A and is to a dwelling, 4/0 aluminum will suffice.  You can buy bundled cable such as MH feeder, or if you are running conduit, you may run individual wires such as XHHW.

The service panel needs a working space kept clear at all times of the width of the panel(s) but at least 30” wide, 36” of stand-back space, and 78” ceiling.   You are best putting it in places that will naturally be kept clear since they are a hallway, threshold or passage.  I get the urge to bury it out of sight out of mind in a little-used corner, but that invites code violations and forces someone to be a "working space nazi".

There is nothing wrong with tankless electric **if you can power it**.  However you need about 40 amps per desired GPM of hot water flow.   *It is NOT instant - a centrally located tankless is actually slower than a tanked heater since **the water is not already hot***.  If you want near instant, install multiple heaters at points of use - like the classic 10.5 kW British electric showers (which have ultra low flow showerheads to make that viable).

Now as far as EV charging, that gets a bad rap because everyone thinks they need the Fastest Charge Possible(tm).  And lots of people burn up lots of hardware in pursuit of this.  Actually, you only need to replace your typical daily usage + an extra 50% to catch up from big days.  For the vast majority of people, a 15A 240V breaker giving 2.9 kW, or a 20A breaker giving 3.8 kW, is enough.  When I commuted 80 mile round trip, either would have sufficed for me.  It certainly doesn't need more than a dryer (5.6 kW).